# Need a serializable list that can be exposed via Interfaces and pass FxCop

Tags: c#, serialization, interface, fxcop

What I need:  I have a class that among its rather complicated data has nested lists.  I need this class to be serialize.  I need to expose this list through interfaces without copying the list (the interface needs to expose the exact list, not a converted copy of it), and I need to pass FXCop.

I had a method of accomplishing this that passed the older versions of FX Cop - I created wrapper classes for my lists.  However FXCop is now flagging my wrapper class and not allowing me to do a set because it doesn't want me to expose the list.  Serialization, on the other hand, hasn't picked up on the fact that its a list and won't serialize without a set.  Has anybody encountered this and if so found a way to get around it?

This is a small example of what I'm trying to do:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace MyExample
{
public class JustSomeData : MyExample.IJustSomeData
{
    public double Elbow
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public double Knees
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public double Toes
    {
        get;
        set;
    }   
}

public class DataCollection : List<IJustSomeData>, IXmlSerializable
{
    private List<IJustSomeData> stuff = new List<IJustSomeData>();

    public DataCollection() : base() { }

    public System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void ReadXml(System.Xml.XmlReader reader)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<JustSomeData>));
        // Use the Deserialize method to restore the object's state.
        this.Clear();
        reader.ReadStartElement();
        List<JustSomeData> data = (List<JustSomeData>)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        this.AddRange(data.ConvertAll(i => i as IJustSomeData));
        reader.ReadEndElement();
    }

    public void WriteXml(System.Xml.XmlWriter writer)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<JustSomeData>));
        // Use the Deserialize method to restore the object's state.
        List<JustSomeData> writeMe = this.ConvertAll(i => i as JustSomeData);
        serializer.Serialize(writer, writeMe);
    }
}

/// <summary>
///  this guy would be exposed through COM/etc
/// </summary>
public class IncredibleDataObject : MyExample.IIncredibleDataObject
{
    DataCollection collection = new DataCollection();  /// I need to expose the same list to customer
                                                       /// without converting it.  Convert all passes back a 
                                                       /// different list!!

    /// <summary>
    /// this guy is used for serialization
    /// </summary>
    public DataCollection DataCollection
    {
        get { return this.collection; }
        set { this.collection = value; }  // <-- Fx cop doesn't like, says I can serialize the collection with 
    }                                     // just the get and to not expose the set.  Serialization thinks otherwise and ignores
                                          // without the get. In the older FXCop version I got away with this!

    /// <summary>
    /// this guy exposed to customer/etc via interface
    /// </summary>
    [XmlIgnore]
    public IList<IJustSomeData> IDataCollection
    {
        get { return this.collection; }
    }
}
}
```

This is my test driver:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;

namespace MyExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IncredibleDataObject me = new IncredibleDataObject();
            IIncredibleDataObject customer = (IIncredibleDataObject)me;
            // This is me
            JustSomeData data = new JustSomeData();
            data.Elbow = 2;
            me.DataCollection.Add(new JustSomeData());
            me.DataCollection.Add(data);

            // Customer
            double shouldBeTwo = customer.IDataCollection[1].Elbow;
            customer.IDataCollection[1].Toes = 10;

            // Me 
            double shouldBeTen = me.DataCollection[1].Toes;

            // Need to be able to do this
            TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\test.xml");
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(IncredibleDataObject));
            // Use the Deserialize method to restore the object's state.
            serializer.Serialize(writer, me);
            writer.Close();

            IncredibleDataObject openData = new IncredibleDataObject();
            TextReader reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\test.xml");
            XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(IncredibleDataObject));
            // Use the Deserialize method to restore the object's state.
            openData = (IncredibleDataObject)deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
            reader.Close();
        }
    }
}
```